# Ways to create a recursive data structure in C

Tags: c, recursion, struct, typedef, definition

Let's say I have some hashmap that can refer to itself, something like:

```
typedef struct Person {
    char* name;
    Person* mother;
    Person* father;
} Person;
```

```
Person *Bob = malloc(sizeof(Person));
bob->name = "Bob";
bob->mother = Kathy;
bob->father = Bill;
```

What are the suggested ways to get around the `error: unknown type name ‘Person’` error?

Comment: Alternatively, put `struct` in front of the fields when declaring them, like so: `struct Person* mother;` and `struct Person* father;`.

Comment: @hgs3 which of the two ways would you think is more common?

Comment: @David542 It comes down to personal preference. In fact, many projects, like the Linux kernel, don't `typedef` their structs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Person` is not defined yet, since the typedef only takes effect after the semicolon concluding it. To refer to the struct from within itself, use `struct Person`. The following code compiles with no errors on GCC 10.2.0.

```c
typedef struct Person {
    char* name;
    struct Person* mother;
    struct Person* father;
} Person;

int main() {
    Person Kathy = { "Kathy", NULL, NULL };
    Person Bill = { "Bill", NULL, NULL };
    Person Bob = { "Bob", &Kathy, &Bill };
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that the name Person used within the structure definition as a type specifier for data members mother and father

```
typedef struct Person {
    char* name;
    Person* mother;
    Person* father;
} Person;
```

is not yet declared.

Either use a typedef before the structure definition like

```
typedef struct Person Person;

struct Person{
    char* name;
    Person* mother;
    Person* father;
};
```

Or use the declared structure tag in the structure definition like

```
typedef struct Person {
    char* name;
    struct Person* mother;
    struct Person* father;
} Person;
```

Comment: is one form preferred over the other? Or it doesn't matter and people use both ways?

Comment: @David542 The first form is often used when in some .c files there are declared pointers to the structure. In this case the full definition of the structure is not required. So the typedef can be placed in one header and the structure definition in another header that includes the header with the typedef.

Answer (score 1):

While the `typedef` is not defined, the `struct` tag is so you can prepend that to the elements of the `struct`. For example:

```
typedef struct Person {
    char* name;
    struct Person* mother;
    struct Person* father;
} Person;
```

```
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void) {

    // parents (ignore their parents)
    Person *Kathy = malloc(sizeof(Person));
    Kathy->name = "Kathy";
    Person *Bill = malloc(sizeof(Person));
    Bill->name = "Bill";

    // person
    Person *Bob = malloc(sizeof(Person));
    Bob->name = "Bob";
    Bob->mother = Kathy;
    Bob->father = Bill;

    printf("Name: %s | Mom: %s, Dad: %s\n", Bob->name, Bob->mother->name, Bob->father->name
    free(Bob); free(Kathy); free(Bill);

}
```

> Name: Bob | Mom: Kathy, Dad: Bill